# Having an icon turn white on hover

Tags: html, css

I wanted the icon to light up white after it's hovered over, however it doesn't seem to work. I tried

```
.lock:hover {
   color: white;
}
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
.lock {
    background: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplius-pack/512/pencil_and_paper-16.png') no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:-5px;
}

.subMenu-link {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

li.subMenu span{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.subMenu:hover {
    background: #191919;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="subMenu">
    <i class="lock"></i> 
    <span>User Account</span>                                   
</li>
```

Here's the output it shows:
[image]

I just simply want the icon to turn white upon hovering. Any ideas what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The color CSS property won't change the color of an image. If it was a transparent image, you could change the background color though.

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the background image on hover.

```
.lock:hover {
 background: url('urIcon.jpg');
 // styles
 }
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense, wtf was i thinking! Thanks!

Comment: I have a quick question though. How come it only changes images once I hover directly over the image, rather than the whole `li` box? http://jsfiddle.net/67byoqr9/1/

Comment: You could use `li:hover + .lock{ code . . . }` for that.  Note that `.lock` must come directly after the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare another image to be displayed when hovered, with the same CSS properties

```
.lock:hover {
    background: url("some/other/image") no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:-5px;
}
```

This will display some-other-image when hovered.

Comment: I have a quick question though. How come it only changes images once I hover directly over the image, rather than the whole li box? jsfiddle.net/67byoqr9/1

Comment: I think it is because the class "lock" is not on the whole li block, just on the small image itself.